# Ember DataStore doesn't appear to work. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: ember.js, datastore

In [this JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eEnVT/) I'm trying to get John (which it does), but then I'm trying to fetch all of John's pets (he should have two), but in fact nothing is returned.

I was under the impression that the DS store would look-up the relationship and fetch the pets for me based on `pet_ids`.

Could somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

By default, the REST adapter expects `pet_ids` to be passed in as `pets`. You can see a working version of your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dgeb/k5geV/).

If you want provide custom mappings, you'll need to use `Adapter.map` as explained in the [breaking changes](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/BREAKING_CHANGES.md#mapping).